# SharePoint Formula =IF(ISBLANK)

Tags: worksheet-function, sharepoint

Is anyone able to tell me how to fix my formula. I have tried everything and I continue to get an error message. I am running out of options.

I am trying to hide the SharePoint default date of 12/30/1904 when a termination date is not entered.

```
=If(ISBLANK[Termination Date]),"",[Termination Date]+1826.21
```

Answer (score 1):

For each function (`IF` and `ISBLANK`) you need to have a pair of parentheses,
surrounding the argument(s) to that function. 
`ISBLANK` takes one argument: the value that you want to check
for whether it is blank. 
`IF` takes three arguments: the Boolean (true/false) value,
the "if true" value, and the "if false" value. 
So your formula should be

```
=If(ISBLANK([Termination Date]),"",[Termination Date]+1826.21)
           ↑                                                 ↑
```